# Append array from another Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to append new element to array. I'm using container view. I call addItem function to tableviewcontroller. But I clicked button nothing happen.

My TableViewController

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myArray = ["1"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func addItem () {
        myArray.append("asd")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return myArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

My TableViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        TableViewController().addItem()
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you understand that every time you call `TableViewController()` it creates a new `TableViewController` with a new array?  I'm guessing you need to use the one you already have instead.

Comment: Are you just trying to pass data from one view controller to another?

Comment: Yes.. But i'm failed.

Answer (score 0):

The line TableViewController().addItem() means create a brand new instance of TableViewController and then call addItem() on it. You need to find a reference to the specific instance of TableViewController you want to manipulate. How does that ViewController relate to the one calling addItem?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableViewController = TableViewController()
    ..

    @IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        tableViewController.addItem()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but nothing happen again...I don't get error but nothing happen.